# How can I make the images equal width

Tags: image, css, html-table, responsive-design

I'm trying to control the images inside the table and keep them on the same level and same width when screen size down. This will be used for email, so I would avoid global styles like `td width` so other elements in the email wont be effected.

The code I am using is:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:414px) {
      .mobile {
        width: 100% !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
}
```

```html
<table border="" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobile" width="600">
  <tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
  <h4 style="line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0 5px"> First title here </h4>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x160/000" style="width: 100%;" />
</td>

<td style="text-align: center;">
  <h4 style="line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0 5px"> SECOND TITLE HERE IN THE MIDDLE</h4>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x160/00c" style="width: 100%;" />
</td>

<td style="text-align: center;">
  <h4 style="line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0 5px ">THEN THIRD TITLE HERE</h4>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x160/c00" style="width: 100%;" />
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why 3 tables inside a table ?

Comment: I honestly have no idea!! @TemaniAfif

Comment: so my advice is to rework this with only one table

Comment: [Check This](https://codepen.io/abdaburagheb/pen/vdLrNd?editors=1100) Something like this ? @TemaniAfif

Comment: yes i think better, and now they will always stay in one line ;) you may control some width to have them equal

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do now but it not working with me for some reason!! @TemaniAfif

Comment: simply add this `td {
  width:33%;
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164439/discussion-between-arsaar-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply `width: 33.33%;` to the table cells.

And if you want the images be aligned to the bottom, add `vertical-align: bottom;` to the cells and apply `display: block` to the images:

```css
td {
  width: 33.33%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

td img {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:414px) {
  .mobile {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobile" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
      <h4 style="line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0 5px"> First title here </h4>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x160/000" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>

    <td style="text-align: center;">
      <h4 style="line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0 5px"> SECOND TITLE HERE IN THE MIDDLE</h4>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x160/00c" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>

    <td style="text-align: center;">
      <h4 style="line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0 5px ">THEN THIRD TITLE HERE</h4>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x160/c00" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The part that was breaking the layout was the text above the images. Try moving it above the images on its seperate row, give it a height and everything works.

```css
 @media only screen and (max-width:414px) {
      .mobile {
        width: 100% !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
 }
```

```html
<table border="" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobile" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; height: 20px;" height="20"><h4 style="line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0 5px"> First title here </h4></td>
    <td style="text-align: center; height: 20px;" height="20"><h4 style="line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0 5px"> SECOND TITLE HERE IN THE MIDDLE</h4></td>
    <td style="text-align: center; height: 20px;" height="20"><h4 style="line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0 5px ">THEN THIRD TITLE HERE</h4></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td width="33%" style="text-align: center;">
  
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x160/000" style="width: 100%;" />
</td>

<td width="33%" style="text-align: center;">
  
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x160/00c" style="width: 100%;" />
</td>

<td width="33%" style="text-align: center;">
  
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x160/c00" style="width: 100%;" />
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Let me know if this works for you.